# When do you use an arrow ($\vec{x}$) in equations?

Tags: vectors, notation

I don't understand when I can use vectors in equations and when not. For example, you have $$E_k = \frac{1}{2}m  v^2 \text{ (here, you don't use $\vec{v}$)}$$
but for example $$\vec{p} = m  \vec{v}$$

I can give a lot more examples. So how do you know when to use the arrow and when not?

Comment: The first equation is one equation. The second is three.

Comment: It’s OK to write $\vec{v}^2$ in the first equation. That is standard shorthand for $\vec v \cdot \vec v$.

Comment: If v is vector then the kinetic energy is $T=\dfrac{1}{2}m\overrightarrow{v}\cdot \overrightarrow{v}$ you can always use vectors ,if you have a vector not scalar

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks elementary research into vector and scalar quantities.

Comment: Don’t write a dot like you did in your two equations. That is used for the scalar product of two vectors.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I really don't think its lacks elementary research as it isn't stated anywhere whether it is ok to use vectors everywhere or not. For example, the definition of $E_{kin}$ is without a vector on wiki. It is really confusing as its nowhere defined what the rules are.

Comment: @G.Smith Thanks for the tip, I removed the dots.

Comment: Is your question about the little arrow above the v or is it about when to use vectors or scalars? In the first case it is a matter of taste and sometimes used to simplify things for beginners (mathematicians will certainly not use it). In the second case, I’m sorry, you have to wait for an answer that suites your way of understanding things (no offence, everybody has his or her own way of learning!)

Comment: @HartmutBraun it is about the little arrow.

Comment: I think most arrows look terrible, especially when done like Eli did with `\overrightarrow` instead of the far more common (and easy) `\vec`. Use bold ($\mathbf x$) or a superscript ($x^i$) to denote a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put in the vector sign when it is necessary to convey the intended meaning.

For example, if you write $p=mv$, this is only a statement relating the *magnitudes* of $\vec p$ and $\vec v$; it doesn’t say they are in the same *direction* like the vector version $\vec p=m\vec v$ relating the actual vectors (or their three *components*) does.

So the rule is “Write what you mean.” If you mean only the magnitude of $\vec v$, write $v$. If you mean the vector itself, write $\vec v$.

By the way, using $\vec x$ for position vectors (as in your title) is a bad idea. It is ambiguous whether $x$ should mean the magnitude of this vector or one of its three components. That’s why $\vec r$ is more common for position.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a vector or not in the first equation.

$E = \frac{1}{2} m \vec{v} \cdot \vec{v}$ is the dot product of a vector with itself.

$E = \frac{1}{2} m v^2$ is the square of the magnitude of that vector.

The result is the same either way.